# Laravel MailableMailer::returnPath undefined, only locally

Tags: php, laravel, email, laravel-5.3

I have a **Laravel 5.3** project in which I inherited a piece of code that sends out an email:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail;

$mail = Mail::to($user->email); 
$result = $mail->returnPath('test@test.com')->send(new InviteMail($data));
```

On my live server this is working fine, but locally I'm getting the following error

> FatalThrowableError in UserService.php line 48:
>   Call to undefined method Illuminate\Mail\MailableMailer::returnPath()

#### What I've done so far

- diff'd both files (local and on the working server): there is no difference
- looked up MailableMailer in the docs: https://laravel.com/api/5.3/Illuminate/Mail/MailableMailer.html
  the **returnPath method indeed doesn't exist** on the MailableMailer class

So I'm wondering how this can work on the live server, but locally this throws the error.

Comment: Most likely on live server you use `composer dump-autoload -o` and that will correct all "namespacing kind of problems", so you have a typo somewhere in use statements. To quickly test it out just run `composer dump-autoload -o` on development machine and see if you are getting the same error. Other things that come in mind are you really sure that you are on same git branch as live server?

Comment: in addition to the above - check your server PHP version and your own.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, The server is at 5.6 and my local development is 7.1, that's probably the issue?

Comment: It might! you need to be as close to your live server as possible... please do regex search for the method and see what comes up (just search in whole project for "returnPath" if you get 2-3 hits just post it here.

Comment: OK I think I found what is going on, what is the driver for mail in live server and what do you use on development server (check .env files).

Comment: Both SMTP, on local it's going to mailtrap, on the live it's using the smtp of the hosting..thanks for your time!

Comment: @Notflip use @ if comment is meant for me so notification pops up... anyway, I bet it has something to do with different configuration maybe facade is pointing to different implementation, but that does not make sense since you have the same code. Open up tinker (`$ artisan tinker`) in prod and dev and type in `get_class(Mail::getFacadeRoot())` is the output the same?

Comment: @Kyslik Thanks for your answer, they are both "Illuminate\Mail\Mailer"

Comment: Make `$ composer update` on both environments, test the thing manually.  Make a diff of output `$ composer info` between prod and dev environment. And also try if you get `true` from tinkering `class_exists('Swift_Message');`. Current code **should not** work on prod because `$mail` is of an instance Mailer not Message (you can use `returnPath(..)` on Message instance).

Comment: class_exists('Swift_Message'); returns TRUE on both environments.. Isn't running 'composer update' on live server bad? Can't things break?

Comment: @Notflip  Make a diff of output `$ composer info` between prod and dev environment.

Comment: Hi @Kyslik you'll never believe this.. The previous development company was dragging the vendor folder in using FTP. There was a real version mismatch.. My goodness..

Comment: @Notflip at least we had some fun ;) cheers.

Comment: True that! Thank you for your time.